# Background on UITableView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

How to show Background image in UITableView Like

[image]

Please help me out. Thank you

Answer (score 14):

Use this

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cloud.png"] ];
self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView;

[imageView release];

self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 9):

Add an UIImageView to the View, ontop of that place the UITableView and set the background color to clearcolor.

Comment: You can also assign images to the background of individual cells using `-[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:UIImage];`

Comment: @TheBlack, that only works correctly if the image can repeat it self.

Answer (score 2):

You can also go ahead and set the background color directly:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"]];
```